# How to rewrite different subdomains as folders within the same site using Netlify

Tags: url-rewriting, netlify

As stated in https://www.netlify.com/blog/2015/10/30/domain-aliasesas-many-as-you-like/ Netlify seems to support this:

> Our flexible rewrite rules also means you can even handle different
>   subdomains as folders within the same site.

But how should this be configured? Seems not documented anywhere.

**EDIT**

I would like to store files in folder `/developer` and serve them from `http://developer.example.com`. So for the user it looks he is browsing `http://developer.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define redirect rules to do this by defining them in a `_redirects` file

To serve content hosted on a subdomain to requests coming to the folder URL:

```
# proxy the request
/my/folder/path  https://subdomain.ofmy.site  200

# redirect the request
/my/folder/path  https://subdomain.ofmy.site  302
```

you can also use wildcards and splats

```
# proxy the request
/my/folder/path/*  https://subdomain.ofmy.site/:splat  200
```

More detailed docs on defining redirects on Netlify: https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/

Comment: Hi Phil, thx for your reply. I'm looking for the opposite. So I want a folder like `/developer` to be served on `http://developer.example.com`

Comment: Maybe this is not possible, and I should instead create a second site hosted on the subdomain.

Comment: @MarcelOverdijk, did you ever find a solution to this, or did you have to create a second Netlify website and use a subdomain as the custom domain?

Comment: @PaulShryock Yes I created a second netlify website for this with the subdomain.

Comment: Womp womp. Guess I might have to bite the bullet and manage multiple websites just to manage a single website with multiple subdomains... Just feels hacky and unnecessary extra work.

Comment: I reached out to Netlify Support via Twitter, and received some helpful responses. Following their directions, I tried adding a CNAME DNS record of `subdomain` pointing to `example.netlify.com`, and then adding a line in my `_redirects` file that is basically the opposite of this answer: `https://subdomain.example.com/* /subdomain/:splat 200!`, but I get a 404 Not Found response when I visit https://subdomain.example.com

Comment: @PaulShryock I found a solution which could be useful for rewriting separate subdomain applications: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537324/how-do-i-setup-subdomains-deployed-through-netlify-on-one-app/55537325#55537325

Comment: The link from @LeanderRodrigues is a good one! Here's another way to accomplish it (needs 2 sites, but has fairly thorough instructions about exactly how to make it work): https://community.netlify.com/t/common-issue-can-i-deploy-multiple-repositories-in-a-single-site/179